# ViewPager shows the last images until the new images is not loading

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

My problem:At first time when i open item screen then the all images will be loaded into viewpager after that when i open new item screen then it is showing the old images untill the new images is not loading.

So i want to clear the old images on viewpager when i open a new item.

how can i clear the last images when i open new item screen?

i have written following code for display images in viewpager:

```
   class productimages extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

            imageUlrList.clear();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", arg[0]));

            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET",
                    params);

            try {
                int success;

                success = json.getInt(TAG_IMAGESUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                    JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PIMAGES);

                    for (int index = 0; index < productObj.length(); index++) {
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(index);

                        imageurl = product.getString(TAG_IMAGEURL);
                        imageUlrList.add(imageurl);
                    }

                } else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            try {
                mViewPager.setAdapter(null);
                mViewSlidingImageAdapter = new ViewSlidingImageAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
                mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewSlidingImageAdapter);
                mViewSlidingImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }
```

My adapter class:

```
  class ViewSlidingImageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewSlidingImageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUlrList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return ViewSlidingImage.newInstance(position, product_url);
        }


    }
```

ViewSlidingImage:

```
public class ViewSlidingImage extends Fragment {

    private String postionOfArray = "";

    static ViewSlidingImage newInstance(int imageNum, String imagePathName) {
        final ViewSlidingImage f = new ViewSlidingImage();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putString("postionOfArray", "" + imageNum);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    public ViewSlidingImage() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        postionOfArray = getArguments().getString("postionOfArray");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_sliding_image, container,
                false);
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tutorial_imageview);


        try {

            String imagePath = SingleProductscreen.imageUlrList.get(Integer
                    .parseInt(postionOfArray));
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(mImageView, imagePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewSlidingImage` loads the `ImageView` with the contents in the `imageUrlList` as below:

```
String imagePath = SingleProductscreen.imageUlrList.get(Integer.parseInt(postionOfArray));
```

So all you need to do is clear this `SingleProductscreen.imageUlrList` in the `onPreExecute`. This way you can make sure that once you call the `productimages` asynctask, the `SingleProductscreen.imageUlrList` is empty and hence there wont be any image to load and it will be blank.

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        SingleProductscreen.imageUlrList.clear();
        mViewSlidingImageAdapter = new ViewSlidingImageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewSlidingImageAdapter);
        mViewSlidingImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you its work. But i have one problem is here is that i want to show `loading image` when images are not loaded completely.
For this i have written `  UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(mImageView, imagePath, R.drawable.loadingsymbol);` but  this symbol is visible. so any solution for this?

Comment: some time it shows that loading image and some time it is not showing images. so is there any solution for that?

Comment: have an `ImageView` with the drawable `loadingSymbol`. In your `onPreExecute` set it's visibility to true. In your `onPostExecute` set it's visibility to false. This way, the loading symbol will be shown until the images are fully loaded.

Comment: But there is already `Imageview` in adapter class. .As you can see in my code above.

Comment: I didn't mean in the adapter, but in the `view_sliding_image.xml`. The imageView should be over your `ViewPager`. This is the simplest way I could think of.

Comment: i have already set 
`android:src="@drawable/loadingsymbol` to `Imageview` in `view_sliding_image.xml`.

Comment: Then just make it visible onPreExecute and gone in onPostExecute

Comment: i still didnt get it.!!! how can i access that xml imageview in my class where there is already set another layout. !